# Cannot make static reference to nonstatic method

Tags: android, static-methods

Having trouble with static and non static methods. I have a project with three fragments. I want to launch some music from each of the three fragments. I have three radio buttons on each fragment. I put the media player in a separate class called global. I made the play routine static so I could call it from either of the fragments. I pass the filename to the play routine.

I get `The method getResources() is undefined for the type Global`.

Source code:

```
try {
            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getResources().getAssets().openFd(fn);
            //AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = contex.getAssets().openFd(fn);
            player.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
            descriptor.close();


            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(this.Context.getFilesDir().getPath() + fn);
            player.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
            //player.setDataSource(fn);
            if (playing==false){
                 player.setLooping(true);
                 player.prepare();
                 player.start();
                 playing = true;
```

How can I get getResources() to work. So I can get the dataSource for the player.

Comment: you need to do some tutorials regarding java, notions of class, instance, static methods...

Comment: @njzk2 You could also just give a few simple hints.

Comment: the only hint I can think of in the case is to start by the basics of java. The OP needs to learn what is the relation between a method and an instance in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want access `getResources()` within your fragments you can just call `getActivity().getResources()` within any methods of your fragments

However if you want to encapsulate all of this in `Global` class you may want to do like this:

```
class Global {
    ...
    public static void playback(Context context) {
        // do stuff with 'context.getResources()'
    }
    ...
}
```

And then use it in format `Global.playback(getActivity());` in your fragments

Comment: then the method getActivity() doesn't work. I get this error. The method getActivity() is undefined for the type Global.

Comment: @user3687805 `getActivity()` is a method for fragments not your Global class

Comment: @user3687805 I've also added more details to my answer please see it!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call getResources() without a context.
So you can do the following:

```
public Global(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    context.getResources(); // etc.
}
```

If you call `getResources()` from activity you can write:

```
getResources();
```

Because it means:

```
Activity.this.getResources()
```

and activity extends context

Comment: When I add (context context) to my global class, I get the red underlines. It says "multiple markers at this line. '(' ')'

Comment: Could you paste here source code of your Global class, please?

Answer (score 0):

The `getResources()` method is not a static method, it is an instance method within the `Context` object, so you cannot access it statically.  You have to have a `Context` object instance in order to call it.